# How can I activate React Dev tool without choosing from menu?

Tags: react-native

I have a windows compunter, and I install a VMWare under windows, then I install latest Mac OS X under VMWare,then I install latest XCode, React Native under the Mac OS X. The Mac OS X using a faking display driver which is not good. For example, the Android studio under my Mac OS X flicker terribly that it is impossible to stand with it. But XCode works fine with my Mac OS so it is enough for developing React Native APP until React Native 0.18.0.

With early version of React Native, I can open XCode and run RN APP with a iPhone 6S Plus emulator. When I press Command + D,the React Devtool pop up on chrome. 
But with RN 0.18.0, when I press Command + D, a menu( with a litter flicker which is wierd because the emulator never flicker) pop up on emulator and I cannot select any item in the menu( I  guess it is because my poor faking display driver). So I have no way to access the Devtool under RN 0.18.0